# Link to a JavaScript function via href

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, href

I'm struggling in linking an HTML link `<a>` with a JavaScript function using Google Apps Script. I tried the following, but it left me with this error message:

"Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'https://script.google.com' from frame with URL 'different url'. The frame attempting navigation must be same-origin with the target if navigating to a javascript: url"

[image]

My code:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", "javascript:test()");
link.textContent = "Click";

//----------------------------------------------
function test() {
    console.log("Test");
}
```

The code is placed in an HTML file between:

```
<script>
</script>
```

Everything is coded in the IDE of Google Apps Script.

Comment: The error message should be added as text, not as image.

Comment: Added the error message as plain text, so that I could get found by search engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the onclick javascript function instead:

```
<a onclick="myFunction()">Click me</a>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: @maxgotstuck Your second comment should be in a separate question

Answer (score 2):

don't use href. Use the onclick event for JavaScript functions.

Answer (score 1):

`href` is an attribute used to define the target of the link. The right attribute to use for click-triggered events is `onclick`.

See the W3C documentation for [href](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) and [onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)